# How to minimize the code here which converts date string into UTC

Tags: java, utc

Converting this string `"2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z"` into a UTC value.

The following works, but is very verbose...

```
protected final LocalDateTime dateTimeOfLoss = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse("2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z"), ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId()));
protected final ZonedDateTime zdt = dateTimeOfLoss.atZone(ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId()));
```

I am going for readability, this is for a test.

Comment: It's fine. It doesn't need "minimizing"

Comment: Well, this *is* an UTC value. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to reach? Readibility? Performance?

Comment: "`ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId())`" -> `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

Comment: `Instant.parse("2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z").atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)`?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ going for readability, this is for a test.

Comment: `Instant.parse("2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you need both of these fields, flip them round to construct the `ZonedDateTime` first. You can then get the `LocalDateTime` without having to specify the zone again:

```
protected final ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.parse("2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z").atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
protected final LocalDateTime dateTimeOfLoss = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: Thanks this is clean and what I was looking for :D

Comment: Still simpler if you need a `ZonedDateTime`: `protected final ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z");`.

Answer (score 4):

### Just parse to `Instant`.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z");
        System.out.println(instant);

        // If you want to convert it to ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // If you want to convert it to OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // If you want to convert it to LocalDate
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime(); // Alternatively, odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z
2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z
2021-04-14T20:51:21.527
```

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline and the value you get on parsing is already in UTC. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### Go for OffsetDateTime

You are not using the right types. Your string value, `2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z`, is appropriate for either an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime`. Your use of `LocalDateTime` in particular seems to indicate to me that you need date and/or time of day, not just the moment in time. If so, go for an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
protected final OffsetDateTime dateTimeOfLoss
        = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-04-14T20:51:21.527Z");
```

Then you should not have any good use for `LocalDateTime` nor `ZonedDateTime`. If you still need one of those, maybe for an API that you cannot change, write a conversion method:

```
protected LocalDateTime getDateTimeOfLossLdt() {
    return dateTimeOfLoss.toLocalDateTime();
}

protected ZonedDateTime getZdt() {
    return dateTimeOfLoss.atZoneSameInstant(dateTimeOfLoss.getOffset());
}
```

### Why?

**`LocalDateTime` is not right:** There are few good uses for `LocalDateTime` at all. Most often date and time is used for establishing a point in time, and your string does that by including the trailing `Z` that denotes offset zero from UTC. By converting to `LocalDateTime` you are discarding that offset and hence losing information about which moment in time you had and getting nothing in return. `LocalDateTime` gives you nothing that `OffsetDateTime` does not give you.

**`ZonedDateTime` is not right:** As I said, your string contains a UTC offset. It does not contain a time zone. Asia/Krasnoyarsk and America/Grand_Turk are examples of time zones. So while a `ZonedDateTime` works, it’s really unmotivated. I think of it as more heavy-weight than you need since a time zone includes historic and known future UTC offsets, information that you cannot meaningfully use here.